# Unrecognizable languages relationship to NP-hard languages

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-hard, semi-decidability

I would like to know if there exists an NP-hard language which is also a member of co-RE\R?
I think it depends if P=NP or not, but i'm not sure.

Can I simply assume NP-hard is in R?

Can you direct me how to think about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **NP**-hard languages arbitrarily high in the arithmetical hierarchy.

To answer your specific question, the complement of the halting problem is **NP**-hard and it's in $\mathrm{coRE}\setminus\mathrm{R}$. To see this, let $M$ be a Turing machine that tries all variable assignments for a $\mathrm{SAT}$ instance.  Let it loop forever if it finds a satisfying assignment and let it halt if it doesn't, or if the input isn't a valid encoding of a $\mathrm{SAT}$ instance.  Now, for any string $x$, $x\in\mathrm{SAT}$ iff $\langle M\rangle,x\in\overline{\mathrm{HALT}}$ so we have a reduction from $\mathrm{SAT}$ to the complement of the halting problem.